# How to Access XACML policy create in wso2is-5.6.0 using API manager wso2am-2.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am new to work on  wso2.

I have created XACML policy in wso2is.

Now i am unable to understand how to create API in wso2AM.

I am following this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML)

But i am confusing step-16, after login API publisher first-step(Design).

1) In API publisher "Design" tab what type of method we should create either "POST" type or "GET" type.

2) How many parameters and What type of parameters we have to use in either "POST" type or "GET" type request in "Design" tab of API publisher.

3) what value we have to send in body while testing API to access XACML policy.